# how to disable scroll when WindowState.Maximized to WindowState.Normal in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

i have been developing a wpf application. Every things is good when i use " **WindowState.Maximized** " But i must add below codes into mainform which has got a metro style menu. I  dislike metro style navigation's scroll how to delete scroll . i added menu's margin 0,0,0,0 but not work. i dislike scroll when i changed Maximized  to normal.How to delete scroll?

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Width = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
            this.Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
            this.Left = 0;
            this.Top = 0;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a nice way for to do this is using converters. You may to create an `IValueDataConver` that converts from the scroll viewer bar visibility property to the window state property, and set the binding two way in the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property or `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property to the `Windows.WindowState` property.

This is good because you do not need to add other wear code in your xaml or in your code behind.

Hoe this could helps you...